# calculus difference question

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the difference between the maximum and minimum values of the function $y = |sin x - 0.75|$

attempt to solve: I began all multiplications on the function without absolute value;

$y' = cos x$ ; finding all the possible solutions after equating the function to zero, yields, in the range between $0$ and $2pi$ : $pi/2$, and$ 1.5pi$. further investigation concludes that; $(pi/2, 0.25)$ global max, $(0,0.25)$ global max, $(2pi,-0.75) $local min , $(1.5pi,-1.75)$ global min.

$delta = |y_{min}|- |y_{max}|  = 1.5 $

Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $\sin{x}$ takes on all values between $-1$ and $1$, we could have for example $\sin{x} = 0.75$ which gives us $$y = |0.75 - 0.75| = 0$$The absolute value could not possibly be negative, so this is the minimum for $y$. Now for the maximum:

We will have the maximum for $|y|$ whenever $y = \sin{x} - 0.75$ is at its maximum or minimum. The minimum turns out to be the best candidate here, $\sin{x} = -1$, which gives us $$y = |-1 - 0.75| = |-1.75| = 1.75$$

Hence the difference between max and min values is $1.75 - 0 = 1.75$.

Comment: pretty good, but why didn't you use derivatives?

Comment: @Bak1139 In this case I already know the minimum and maximum values of $\sin{x}$ and so I don't have to, but for a more complicated function I probably would.

Comment: got it, thanks man..